# Xamarin - System.IO.File - namespace 'File' does not exist

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to load a local json file into a string such that I can parse/deserialize it into an object.

However for some reason despite all the examples and the Xamarin support documentation suggesting I can use `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(...)` I get the following error:

[c# error: 'File' type or namespace name not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg67t.png)

My code seems pretty simple, I can't get past loading the file, which seems like it should be so simple!

```
string jsonInput = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("example.json", Encoding.UTF8);
Quiz temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Quiz>(jsonInput);
```

My header includes System.IO amongst the rest too..

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel; //ObservableCollection
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;`
```

**I've also tried the following solution:**

```
            var assembly = typeof(LoadResourceText).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("example.json");
            string jsonInput = "";
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                jsonInput = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

However in this case `'LoadResourceText'` is not found and I can't work out what type should replace it.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**My first post on StackOverflow, hope I did it right..**

Comment: Hi! Sorry for my poor english, but I did struggled a lot with this kind of things too. If you are using Xamarin.Forms, be sure to don't implement the specific platform code at the PCL project. The PCL's .Net Framework package is a little bit different of those we know outside xamarin... You need to use the dependency injection to get this working. Take a look here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Saving_and_Loading_Files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using this file as a local resource, make sure that it is available for each device, for example, in the Android project, select the file/properties/advanced/build action and set it to embedded resource.
Sometimes the code is fine, it's just that the file 'doesn't exist' for the device

Comment: Thanks DHLopez, although I think the issue here is more with the system.io.file namespace as the compiler doesn't like it...

Comment: And in the end, your answer was exactly what I said :) I feel the same way with Xamarin, still new for me, love it, but sometimes it's a pain

Answer (score 0):

^See above response as well^

I have solved this myself.

I found my answer hidden in a forum post by **YkshLeo** on the Xamarin Forums:

> "...make sure the **Build Action for your resource is set to "Embedded Resource"**

I really wish Xamarin would make their documentation a little more thorough. Maybe it's my .Net noobness coming through.